# How to start tail in konsole with subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess, tail

I am using tail to output the listing from a solver using:

```
outputListing = exportFileName.split(".pc")[0] + ".out" 
solver_run = subprocess.Popen([solver_path, "-visual", "-solvargs", "-nt 4 -fp 2", exportFilePath, outputListing])
if os.sep == "\\":
    subprocess.Popen(["wintail",outputListing], shell = True)
elif os.sep == "/":
    if os.environ.get("DESKTOP_SESSION") == 'gnome'
        subprocess.Popen(["gnome-terminal", "-e","tail -f " + outputListing])
    elif os.environ.get("DESKTOP_SESSION") == 'kde'
        subprocess.Popen(["konsole", "-e","tail -f " + outputListing])
```

with this call the solver listing is output in GNOME, but in KDE only the only the terminal (konsole) is started, but no tail is executed. So probably I have to replace "-e" and "tail -f" accordingly. Any ideas for the right call?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution by myself. One have to use:

```
subprocess.Popen(["konsole", "-e","$SHELL", "-c","tail -f " + outputListing])
```

so the key was to add "$SHELL" and "-c" to the call